# List of Owners for Site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to find out all the site owners within a site. (I need to run this for 100 sites).  Please note I am not looking for Site Collections Admins. I am using Sharepoint 2007.  I have been trying to solve this issue for weeks but have had no joy so please help. I am new to Sharepoint so if I am missing something simple please pardon my ignorance.  I tried your power shell command and it bought up to enter the site url which I put in and got the error message below:-

New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:4 char:23
+ $rootSite = New-Object <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

- You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
  At line:20 char:18

  - $site.Dispose <<<< ()
  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dispose:String) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:23 char:18
+ $rootSite.Dispose <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dispose:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Thanks
Romario